# django - call a view multiple times with different parameters

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a django view that takes as parameter a path and returns the list of objects inside that path.
I need to call this view multiple times with different paths.

This is an example like my view:

```
python views.py

def filelist(request, foo):
    files = os.listdir(foo)
    context = { 'files' : files, }
    return render(request,'template2.html', context)
```

The urls.py is like:

```
python urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('filelist/<str:path>/', views.filelist, name = "filelist"),
    ]
```

The template is like this one:

```
HTML template.html

  <div class="collapse">
       <div class="one">
       {% include 'template2.html' %}
       </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse">
       <div class="two">
       {% include 'template2.html' %}
       </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  $(".one").load("{% url 'filelist' 'path1' %}", function() {
  alert( "Ok1" );
  });
  $(".two").load("{% url 'filelist' 'path2' %}", function() {
  alert( "Ok2" );
  });
  </script>
```

Everything works but the variable `{{ files }}` is always the same. 
Inside template2.html there is only a for loop that shows the files' names.

Any help? There is the possibility to store the variable `{{ files }}` in some local variables and then use it inside a `{% for f in files %}` loop? 
Thanks.

Comment: use this `os.chdir(foo)` and then `os.listdir(foo)`

Answer (score 0):

I did it.
If someone else has this problem, my solution is the following:

```
HTML template.html

<a class="btn btn-light btn-s" id="buttonone">1</a>
<a class="btn btn-light btn-s" id="buttontwo">2</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonone").click(function(event){
        $('.one').load("{% url 'filelist' 'path1' %}");
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttontwo").click(function(event){
        $('.two').load("{% url 'filelist' 'path2' %}");
        });
    });
</script>
```